# Get data through xhr from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get some data from a PHP file which only gives a number after executing:

```
<?php
    include '../assets/class/login/loginsys.php';
    $extension = new extension;     
    $count = $extension->userCount();
    echo $count;        
?>
```

So the `$count` variable will be just a number. And I'm trying to retrieve that number and put it in a js variable for further use ( I need it a few times, if it were only once I would have used `$.get()` and applied it to the container I need ):

```
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();  
oXHR.open("GET", "admin/user-count.php", true);  
oXHR.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {  
    if (oXHR.readyState === 4) {  
        if (oXHR.status === 200) {  
            console.log(oXHR.responseText)  
        } else {  
        console.log("Error", oXHR.statusText);  
        }  
    }  
}; 
oXHR.send();
```

I have tried the method above with little success, but I also tried it like this:

```
var users = $.get('admin/user-count.php', function(data) {
    console.log('There are '+data+' users found');
    return data;
});
```

The same result, nothing. So what am I doing wrong or how should I do it right ?

**EDIT** I have made a little mistake that I fixed now, the first method works as well as the second one. but now I need to store the data I get with the first method into a variable so I can use it later on. How do I do that and also which of the two methods is better ?

Comment: Did you check the debug console in your browser (net tab) to eliminate any obvious issues like misspelled filenames?

Comment: Have you tried debugging using Firebug or Fiddler to see if there's anything useful in the request/response chain?

Comment: Did you try to call the php code directly. Does it return the count?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. But, I see now that the first method works now, I had to replace `xhr.sedn()` with the initiated varible `oXHR`. Though I'm not sure how to store the data into a global variable ?!

Comment: `myGlobalVar = parseInt(oXHR.responseText, 10);`

Comment: @ComFreek - I guess I add that after `oXHR.send()` ?

Comment: @Roland No that should be in your `if (oXHR.status===200)` block because you have to wait for the result.

Comment: @ComFreek - Indeed, I just tested and only doing that works, but when I trying to see in the console the var I have declared there it shows me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the second code if you already have jQuery included:

```
$.get('admin/user-count.php', function(data)
{
  // Don't use "var" here, otherwise the variable won't be global!
  myGlobalVar = parseInt(data, 10);
  // Also possible: window["myGlobalVar"] = parseInt(data, 10);
});
```

If you want to use pure JavaScript:

```
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();  
oXHR.open("GET", "admin/user-count.php", true);  
oXHR.onload = function(evt)
{
  myGlobalVar = parseInt(oXHR.responseText,10);
}
oXHR.onerror = function(evt)
{
  alert("Error!");
}
oXHR.send();
```

Comment: I was wondering if using the XMLHttpRequest object isn't better ?

Comment: You can but it will only be faster for some nanoseconds!

Comment: Neither way makes the variable global, Let's say I'm using the second method, now if I doing this `console.log(theDeclaredVar)` outside the `$.get()` function I get nothing, just inside it. Why is that ?

Comment: Here's a test: http://jsfiddle.net/t32as/ Are you sure that you log the variable _after_ the AJAX callback has been called? Otherwise the browser doesn't know about this variable yet!

Comment: Yes, here's the code: `$.get('admin/user-count.php', function(data) {
     console.log('There are '+data+' users found');
     var counter = parseInt(data, 10);
 });`

Comment: Remove the `var` which makes the variable local and not global.

Comment: I just did and yet the same result ? May it be something else wrong ? Maybe a conflict with other code ?

Comment: The problem is that you directly use the variable, you don't wait for the AJAX callback so the variable isn't defined for the browser!

Comment: OK, so how should the code look then ? Because I'm having trouble with other things too which I'm not sure why occurred ...

Comment: You can put the code which relies on the AJAX response into a function  which you call in the AJAX callback. See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khCJh/1/

Comment: I see now, so everything has to be as callback of the `$.get()` function. I thought there was a way around that but that works fine too :)

Comment: You could do a synchronous request but that can block the UI and can cause other problems! I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I see, no problem though, it's fine the way it is. If I had some other question would it be possible to talk in chat here ?

Comment: Sure but for more complex questions you should ask a real question on StackOverflow.